# Solving ODE numerically with Python

Tags: python, physics

I am solving an ODE for an harmonic oscillator numerically with Python. When I add a driving force it makes no difference, so I'm guessing something is wrong with the code. Can anyone see the problem? The `(h/m)*f0*np.cos(wd*i)` part is the driving force.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This code solves the ODE mx'' + bx' + kx = F0*cos(Wd*t)
# m is the mass of the object in kg, b is the damping constant in Ns/m
# k is the spring constant in N/m, F0 is the driving force in N,
# Wd is the frequency of the driving force and x is the position 

# Setting up

timeFinal= 16.0   # This is how far the graph will go in seconds
steps = 10000     # Number of steps
dT = timeFinal/steps      # Step length 
time = np.linspace(0, timeFinal, steps+1)   
# Creates an array with steps+1 values from 0 to timeFinal

# Allocating arrays for velocity and position
vel = np.zeros(steps+1)
pos = np.zeros(steps+1)

# Setting constants and initial values for vel. and pos.
k = 0.1
m = 0.01
vel0 = 0.05
pos0 = 0.01
freqNatural = 10.0**0.5
b = 0.0
F0 = 0.01
Wd = 7.0
vel[0] = vel0    #Sets the initial velocity
pos[0] = pos0    #Sets the initial position



# Numerical solution using Euler's
# Splitting the ODE into two first order ones
# v'(t) = -(k/m)*x(t) - (b/m)*v(t) + (F0/m)*cos(Wd*t)
# x'(t) = v(t)
# Using the definition of the derivative we get
# (v(t+dT) - v(t))/dT on the left side of the first equation
# (x(t+dT) - x(t))/dT on the left side of the second 
# In the for loop t and dT will be replaced by i and 1

for i in range(0, steps):
    vel[i+1] = (-k/m)*dT*pos[i] + vel[i]*(1-dT*b/m) + (dT/m)*F0*np.cos(Wd*i)
    pos[i+1] = dT*vel[i] + pos[i]

# Ploting
#----------------
# With no damping
plt.plot(time, pos, 'g-', label='Undampened')

# Damping set to 10% of critical damping
b = (freqNatural/50)*0.1

# Using Euler's again to compute new values for new damping
for i in range(0, steps):
    vel[i+1] = (-k/m)*dT*pos[i] + vel[i]*(1-(dT*(b/m))) + (F0*dT/m)*np.cos(Wd*i)
    pos[i+1] = dT*vel[i] + pos[i]

plt.plot(time, pos, 'b-', label = '10% of crit. damping')
plt.plot(time, 0*time, 'k-')      # This plots the x-axis
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')

#---------------
plt.show()
```

Comment: For those of us that haven't been solving differential equations lately, this code is *very* hard to read. I can't immediately tell which method you're using. Euler's? To get more help, you could try using meaningful names for variables and commenting the code a bit

Comment: I understand, I will add some comments and repost.

Comment: I think you should generally add more comments and first and foremost use more descriptive variable names

Comment: What do you mean by "making no difference"? I just ran this code, varied F0 value, and saw that it makes some difference in the results.

Also, I think `timeFinal` is `tF`, `steps` is `N`, `w` in `b = (w/50)*0.1` is `Wd` in your code. Is that right?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the w in the damping constant is the natural frequency of the system, freqNatural.

Comment: The code does not even run... Where are tFinal and N defined?

Comment: Missed them during editing, fixed now.

Comment: To everyone asking for clearer variable name: in more mathematically oriented code, these short variable names are actually a lot better. First, they match the names in the mathematical formulas, making them more easily recognizable. Second, the formulas are pretty long and having short variable names helps.

Comment: @PaulManta - Agreed. When it comes to numerical programming, variable names that match the mathematical literature are oftentimes preferred over the kinds of names taught in computer science classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is with the term `np.cos(Wd*i)`.  It should be `np.cos(Wd*i*dT)`, that is note that `dT` has been added into the correct equation, since `t = i*dT`.

If this correction is made, the simulation looks reasonable.  Here's a version with `F0=0.001`.  Note that the driving force is clear in the continued oscillations in the damped condition.

[image]

The problem with the original equation is that `np.cos(Wd*i)` just jumps randomly around the circle, rather than smoothly moving around the circle, causing no net effect in the end.  This can be best seen by plotting it directly, but the easiest thing to do is run the original form with `F0` very large.  Below is `F0 = 10` (ie, 10000x the value used in the correct equation), but using the incorrect form of the equation, and it's clear that the driving force here just adds noise as it randomly moves around the circle.

[image]

Comment: Happy to help.  By the way, if this isn't just a programming exercise, it may be helpful to know that this is a fairly common equation, not very hard to solve with pencil and paper, and is probably solved in the first couple of chapters in any differential equations text, wolfram alpha, etc.  (difficulty is sophomore or junior year undergrad if you're into physics/math/engineering/etc)  Also, done, eg, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112583/complementary-solution-homogenous-solution

Comment: We are actually asked specifically to solve these numerically in Python. I guess it's to show the pros and cons of numerical solving compared to analytical.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your ODE is well behaved and has an analytical solution. So you could utilize sympy for an alternate approach:

```
import sympy as sy    
sy.init_printing()  # Pretty printer for IPython

t,k,m,b,F0,Wd = sy.symbols('t,k,m,b,F0,Wd', real=True)  # constants

consts = {k:  0.1, # values
          m:  0.01,
          b:  0.0,
          F0: 0.01,
          Wd: 7.0}

x = sy.Function('x')(t)  # declare variables
dx = sy.Derivative(x, t)
d2x = sy.Derivative(x, t, 2)

# the ODE:
ode1 = sy.Eq(m*d2x + b*dx + k*x, F0*sy.cos(Wd*t))

sl1 = sy.dsolve(ode1, x) # solve ODE
xs1 = sy.simplify(sl1.subs(consts)).rhs # substitute constants


# Examining the solution, we note C3 and C4 are superfluous
xs2 = xs1.subs({'C3':0, 'C4':0})
dxs2 = xs2.diff(t)

print("Solution x(t) = ")
print(xs2)
print("Solution x'(t) = ")
print(dxs2)
```

gives

```
Solution x(t) = 
C1*sin(3.16227766016838*t) + C2*cos(3.16227766016838*t) - 0.0256410256410256*cos(7.0*t)
Solution x'(t) = 
3.16227766016838*C1*cos(3.16227766016838*t) - 3.16227766016838*C2*sin(3.16227766016838*t) + 0.179487179487179*sin(7.0*t)
```

The constants `C1,C2` can be determined by evaluating `x(0),x'(0)` for the initial conditions.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. Unfortunately, we are not using sympy in this physics course (only numpy and matplotlib), and quite frankly I don't think I've got time to learn it.